# AIOgram проблемы со state

Tags: python, aiogram, бот, state

Я пишу бота на aiogram и частенько возникает такая ошибка, когда хочу обратиться к состоянию. Была ли у кого-то такая же? Как фиксили?

Я пытался по другому работать со state.

```
await state.update_data(name=message.text)
await state.set_state(Form.some_field)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код из файла

```
import datetime
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Optional

from aiogram import Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup

from database import (
    CompletedPracticesActions,
    GroupActions,
    QueueActions,
    ScheduleActions,
    SubjectActions,
    UserActions,
)
from enums import HeadmanCommands, ScheduleActionsEnum, SubjectActionsEnum
from keywords import (
    choice_schedule,
    get_list_of_subjects,
    schedule_action,
    select_cancel,
    select_days,
    select_subject_passes,
    subject_action,
)
from services import (
    check_headman_of_group,
    get_info_schedule,
    get_schedule_name,
)

FIRST_DAY = datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1)
START_MESSAGE = """"""


def nice_schedule(
    schedule: list,
    day: int,
    on_even_week: Optional[bool],
) -> bool:
    """Check schedule to exists."""
    return not list(filter(
        lambda x: (
            x["date_number"] == day and
            x["on_even_week"] == on_even_week
        ),
        schedule,
    ))


@dataclass
class ScheduleCompact:
    """Class for send schedule in keyboard."""

    id: int
    name: str


class Subject(StatesGroup):
    """FSM for edit subject."""

    action = State()
    name_update_delete = State()
    name_create = State()
    schedule_action = State()
    schedule_delete = State()
    week = State()
    days = State()
    count = State()


async def start_subject(message: types.Message) -> None:
    """Entrypoint for subject."""
    await message.answer(START_MESSAGE)
    await Subject.action.set()
    await message.answer("Выберите действие", reply_markup=subject_action())


async def input_action_subject(
    callback: types.CallbackQuery,
    state: FSMContext,
) -> None:
    """Input action for subject."""
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data["action"] = callback.data
    match callback.data:
        case SubjectActionsEnum.CANCEL.action:
            await callback.message.answer("Действие отменено")
            await state.finish()
        case SubjectActionsEnum.CREATE.action:
            await Subject.name_create.set()
            await callback.message.answer(
                "Введите название дисциплины",
                reply_markup=select_cancel(),
            )
        case (
            SubjectActionsEnum.DELETE.action |
            SubjectActionsEnum.UPDATE.action
        ):
            await Subject.name_update_delete.set()
            subjects = GroupActions.get_group(
                UserActions.get_user(callback.from_user.id).group,
                subjects=True,
            ).subjects
            if not subjects:
                await callback.message.answer("Изменять нечего.")
                await Subject.action.set()
                await callback.message.answer(
                    "Выберите действие",
                    reply_markup=subject_action(),
                )
                return
            await callback.message.answer(
                "Выберите дисциплину",
                reply_markup=get_list_of_subjects(subjects),
            )


async def input_name_update_delete_subject(
    callback: types.CallbackQuery,
    state: FSMContext,
) -> None:
    """Input name of subject."""
    group = GroupActions.get_group(
        UserActions.get_user(callback.from_user.id).group,
        subjects=True,
    )
    subject = list(filter(
        lambda x: x.id == int(callback.data),
        group.subjects,
    ))[0]
    schedule = ScheduleActions.get_schedule(subject.id)
    schedule = (
        list(map(lambda x: x.__dict__, schedule))
        if schedule is not None else []
    )
    action = ""
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        action = data["action"]
        data["name"] = subject.name
        data["schedule"] = schedule
        data["subject_id"] = subject.id
        data["to_update"] = True
    match action:
        case SubjectActionsEnum.UPDATE.action:
            await callback.message.answer(get_info_schedule(subject.id))
            await Subject.schedule_action.set()
            await callback.message.answer(
                "Выберите действие для расписания",
                reply_markup=schedule_action(),
            )
        case SubjectActionsEnum.DELETE.action:
            QueueActions.cleaning_subject(subject.id)
            CompletedPracticesActions.cleaning_subject(subject.id)
            ScheduleActions.delete_schedule_by_subject(subject.id)
            SubjectActions.delete_subject(subject.id)
            await callback.message.answer("Предмет успешно удален")
            await state.finish()


async def input_name_subject(
    message: types.Message,
    state: FSMContext,
) -> None:
    """Get name of new or exists subject."""
    group = GroupActions.get_group(
        UserActions.get_user(message.from_user.id).group,
        subjects=True,
    )
    subject = list(filter(
        lambda x: x.name == message.text,
        group.subjects,
    ))
    if subject:
        await message.answer(
            (
                "Предмет с таким названием уже есть в группе. "
                "Введите другое название."
            ),
            reply_markup=select_cancel(),
        )
        return
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        if data.get("to_update", False) is not True:
            data["schedule"] = []
        data["name"] = message.text
    await Subject.schedule_action.set()
    await message.answer(
        "Выберите действие для расписания",
        reply_markup=schedule_action(),
    )


async def input_schedule_action(
    callback: types.CallbackQuery,
    state: FSMContext,
) -> None:
    """Input action of schedule."""
    schedule = []
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        schedule = data["schedule"]
    match callback.data:
        case ScheduleActionsEnum.ADD.action:
            await Subject.week.set()
            await callback.message.answer(
                "Выберите, как будет проходить предмет",
                reply_markup=select_subject_passes(),
            )
        case ScheduleActionsEnum.DELETE.action:
            if schedule:
                schedule_list = [
                    ScheduleCompact(
                        name=get_schedule_name(item),
                        id=item["id"],
                    )
                    for item in schedule
                ]
                await Subject.schedule_delete.set()
                await callback.message.answer(
                    "Выберите расписание, которое нужно удалить",
                    reply_markup=choice_schedule(schedule_list),
                )
                return
            await callback.message.answer("Удалять нечего.")
            await Subject.schedule_action.set()
            await callback.message.answer(
                "Выберите действие для расписания",
                reply_markup=schedule_action(),
            )
        case ScheduleActionsEnum.NEXT_ACTION.action:
            await Subject.count.set()
            await callback.message.answer(
                "Введите количество лабораторных работ",
                reply_markup=select_cancel(),
            )
        case ScheduleActionsEnum.CANCEL.action:
            await callback.message.answer("Действие отменено")
            await state.finish()


async def delete_schedule_action(
    callback: types.CallbackQuery,
    state: FSMContext,
) -> None:
    """Delete schedule."""
    subject_id = None
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        subject_id = data.get("subject_id", None)
        if subject_id is not None:
            ScheduleActions.delete_schedule_by_id(int(callback.data))
        data["schedule"] = list(filter(
            lambda x: x["id"] != callback.data,
            data["schedule"],
        ))
    if subject_id is not None:
        await callback.message.answer(get_info_schedule(subject_id))
    await Subject.schedule_action.set()
    await callback.message.answer(
        "Выберите действие для расписания",
        reply_markup=schedule_action(),
    )


async def input_week_subject(
    callback: types.CallbackQuery,
    state: FSMContext,
) -> None:
    """Input type of week of subject."""
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data["on_even_week"] = (
            True
            if callback.data == "True"
            else False if callback.data == "False" else None
        )
    await Subject.next()
    await callback.message.answer(
        "Выберите дни, в которые будет проходить предмет с выбранной неделей",
        reply_markup=select_days(),
    )


async def input_date_subject(
    callback: types.CallbackQuery,
    state: FSMContext,
) -> None:
    """Input date of subject."""
    new_schedules, days = [], []
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        message = "Вы завершили выбор"
        if callback.data != "Stop":
            if data.get("days") is None:
                data["days"] = [callback.data]
                message = f"Добавлен {callback.data} день"
            else:
                if nice_schedule(
                    data["schedule"],
                    callback.data,
                    data["on_even_week"],
                ):
                    if callback.data not in data["days"]:
                        data["days"].append(callback.data)
                        message = f"Добавлен {callback.data} день"
                    else:
                        data["days"].remove(callback.data)
                        message = f"Удален {callback.data} день"
                else:
                    message = "Расписание с такими параметрами уже существует"
                    data["already_exists"] = True
        days = data["days"] if data.get("days") is not None else []
        await callback.message.answer(message)
        if callback.data == "Stop":
            for day in days:
                match data["action"]:
                    case SubjectActionsEnum.CREATE.action:
                        new_schedules.append(
                            {
                                "id": (
                                    datetime.datetime.now() - FIRST_DAY
                                ).total_seconds(),
                                "date_number": day,
                                "on_even_week": data["on_even_week"],
                            }
                        )
                    case SubjectActionsEnum.UPDATE.action:
                        item = {
                            "date_number": day,
                            "on_even_week": data["on_even_week"],
                            "subject_id": data.get("subject_id"),
                        }
                        new_schedules.append(
                            ScheduleActions.create_schedule(item)
                        )
            data["schedule"].extend(new_schedules)
            data["days"] = []
            subject_id = data.get("subject_id", None)
            if subject_id is not None:
                await callback.message.answer(get_info_schedule(subject_id))
            await Subject.schedule_action.set()
            await callback.message.answer(
                "Выберите действие для расписания",
                reply_markup=schedule_action(),
            )
            return


async def input_count_lab_subject(
    message: types.Message,
    state: FSMContext,
) -> None:
    """Input count of lab of subject."""
    if not message.text.isdigit():
        await message.answer(
            "Введите количество лабораторных работ",
            reply_markup=select_cancel(),
        )
        return
    if int(message.text) <= 0:
        await message.answer(
            "Введите количество лабораторных работ",
            reply_markup=select_cancel(),
        )
        return
    group = UserActions.get_user(message.from_user.id).group
    action = ""
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        match data["action"]:
            case SubjectActionsEnum.CREATE.action:
                subject_info = {
                    "name": data["name"],
                    "group": group,
                    "count": message.text,
                }
                subject = SubjectActions.create_subject(subject_info)
                for day in data["schedule"]:
                    day.pop("id")
                    day["subject_id"] = subject.id
                    ScheduleActions.create_schedule(day)
                action = "создан"
            case SubjectActionsEnum.UPDATE.action:
                subject_info = {
                    "name": data["name"],
                    "group": group,
                    "count": message.text,
                }
                SubjectActions.update_subject(
                    data["subject_id"],
                    subject_info,
                )
                action = "обновлен"
        await state.finish()
        await message.answer(f"Предмет {data['name']} успешно {action}.")


def register_handlers_subject(dispatcher: Dispatcher) -> None:
    """Register handlers for subject."""
    dispatcher.register_message_handler(
        start_subject,
        lambda message: check_headman_of_group(message.from_user.id),
        commands=[HeadmanCommands.EDIT_SUBJECT.command],
        state=None,
    )
    dispatcher.register_callback_query_handler(
        input_action_subject,
        state=Subject.action,
    )
    dispatcher.register_callback_query_handler(
        input_name_update_delete_subject,
        state=Subject.name_update_delete,
    )
    dispatcher.register_message_handler(
        input_name_subject,
        state=Subject.name_create,
    )
    dispatcher.register_callback_query_handler(
        input_schedule_action,
        state=Subject.schedule_action,
    )
    dispatcher.register_callback_query_handler(
        delete_schedule_action,
        state=Subject.schedule_delete,
    )
    dispatcher.register_callback_query_handler(
        input_week_subject,
        state=Subject.week,
    )
    dispatcher.register_callback_query_handler(
        input_date_subject,
        state=Subject.days,
    )
    dispatcher.register_message_handler(
        input_count_lab_subject,
        state=Subject.count,
    )
```

Comment: Какая версия айограма? Покажите код где происходит ошибка

Comment: @oleksandrigo, aiogram 2.21. Файл добавил

Comment: Попробуй обновить до 2.22. Хз поможет ли правда, но попытка не пытка